# Where to test SSML in Google Action Console

Tags: actions-on-google, ssml

In the Google Action Console I would like to test how Google Assistant would speak some text like `<speak>Hello world</speak>` without having to change my action.
I've read I could "Select ‘Simulator’ from the left-hand navigation". But there is no "left-hand navigation".

[image: Google Actions Console]

Where can I find such an SSML simulator?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the homepage for [Google Cloud TTS](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech) to enter some SSML and see how it sounds. Alternatively you can use the [visual editor Nightingale](https://actions-on-google-labs.github.io/nightingale-ssml-editor/) and export to SSML after assembling some audio.